# Show div between mon-fri 9-5 jquery

Tags: javascript, html, time, load

Just need a bit of help with getting a div to fire between mon-fri 9-5:

**HTML**

```
<div class="liveperson">

<!-- Start liveperson code -->
<!-- End Liveperson code -->
</div>
```

**jQ**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var rightNow = getHours(); 
    var day = rightNow.getUTCDay();
    if (day == 1-5 || rightNow == 9-13) { 
      $('.liveperson').show(); 
    }

});
```

Can't tell what it is I'm doing wrong!

Any help would be muchly appreciated!

Thanks in advance people!

Comment: You can't do `== 1-5` that's `==-4` , you need `((day >= 1) && (day <=5))`

Comment: This approach is not good at all. JavaScript will get the time of the local machine viewing the page and not the web server, therefore visiting in different time zones will show your live support when you will be offline. You need to find a server based solution for this type of task, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
var hour = d.getHours();

if (dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 6 && hour > 8 && hour < 17) {
    $('.liveperson').hide();
}
```

`dayOfWeek` is 0-6, Sunday (0) through Saturday (6).

`hour` is is 0-23 (0 being 12 am, 23 being 11 pm).

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tLA8A/)

Comment: Because i've been a bit of an idiot here, and thought that I needed to hide the div between those times (instead of show it) I've changed your code a little, making3. See if it makes sense... 

`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var d = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
    var hour = d.getHours();

    if (dayOfWeek => 6 && dayOfWeek <= 0 && hour => 17 && hour <= 9) {
        jQuery('.slide-out-div').hide();
    }

});
</script>`

Comment: @user2095569 You will need to switch to using ||'s instead of &&'s if you're doing the opposite (so you will show if any of those conditions are met, not just all):
`if (dayOfWeek == 6 || dayOfWeek == 0 || hour <= 9 || hour >= 17`)`

Comment: Hi there @user2095569, thanks for your input...

It's still being a bit of a pig in jsFiddle, as you can see here... It's after 17 now so it shouldn't show, correct?

(http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/PYbkb/2/)

Comment: I thought since it's after 17, it should hide? The hour here is currently 11, and when I set hour >= 11, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get current time
var d = new Date(), 
hours = d.getHours(),
mins = d.getMinutes();
day = d.getDay();   

// if day is mon-Fri and time is between 9am and 5:30pm
if(0 < dday < 6   
    && hours >= 9 
    && (hours < 17 || hours === 17 && mins <= 30)){

    $('.liveperson').show(); 
 };
```

This should do it.